# Python: strptime not matching format

Tags: python, time, strptime

> ValueError: time data '03-10-2011
>   04:35 PM' does not match format
>   '%m-%d-%Y %I:M %p'

That looks like it matches to me?

```
 datetime = datestr + " " + timestr
 date_struct = time.strptime(datetime, "%m-%d-%Y %I:M %p")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing a `%` right before the `M`:

```
 date_struct = time.strptime(datetime, "%m-%d-%Y %I:%M %p")
```

Answer (score 4):

Those datetime format strings work both ways, so you can easily check hypotheses such as "looks like it matches":

```
>>> import datetime
>>> fmt = "%m-%d-%Y %I:M %p"
>>> dt = datetime.datetime(2011, 3, 10, 16, 35)
>>> dt.strftime(fmt)
'03-10-2011 04:M PM' # Oops!
>>>
```